# JAVA SQLException error message sometimes not parsed

Tags: java, oracle

I am new to JDBC, and I found something strange when I use:

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error STATE: " + e.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("With the following message: " + e.getMessage() );
}
```

Sometimes the message is parsed, but sometimes not.

Like:

First:
[image]

Second:
[image]

One is parsed, while the other is not, but I can get the error message through googling the corresponding error code.

I don't know what's going on.. And I have tried googling it but with no similar question posted. Does it mean my java.sql.* library is incomplete?

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the error text inline, and as simple text, not as an image.

Comment: This seems like some of your exceptions may have their messages coming from a different localization.

Comment: i'd suggest to debug it and see exactly what is stored in the exception variable at the time

Comment: Also note that your first message is not the output of the code you have shown. In your code, `STATE` is in capitals, and the message is prefixed with `With the following message` - and these do not appear in your first output.

Comment: Right, they are basically same.. I just adjust what is in front in different scenerios...

Comment: They happen in different places. The first is in login method, while the second is in creating tables method.

Comment: Which driver are you using; and which locale (country and language) for the database, session and operating system? It looks like perhaps you're picking up English messages by default before connecting, but once connected are trying to display a different language, with symbols which your OS can't interpret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your operating system settings don't support the symbols for the error message in the language being used. The ORA-01017 message is coming before the database  applies your language setting so in in English, and more importantly in Western script. Once you've connected the Java locale is honoured.

For example, I can see both these from the same code run with `java -Duser.language=zh -Duser.country=CN`; the first has incorrect credentials supplied, the second is trying to create an existing table:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: 名称已由现有对象使用
```

I'm seeing ten symbols, where you are seeing ten question marks. My operating system session (Linux in this case) has `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. If I change that to something which has fewer symbols defined, e.g. `export LANG="en_US.ASCII"`, I still see the first message but now I get the same as you for the second one:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: ??????????
```

The Chinese symbols can now no longer be rendered by my operating system session.

So set your operating system locale to something that can represent the symbols of the language you're using, preferably UTF8. For example, if Java is running with a Chinese locale, you could do this to be consistent under Linux:

```
export LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
java -Duser.language=zh -Duser.country=CN

ORA-00955: 名称已由现有对象使用
```

Or change your Java locale to English-language if you want to see all the messages in English:

```
export LANG="en_CN.UTF-8"
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=CN -

ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

(Although Java should pick up the language from your locale by default anyway, so maybe don't supply the language or country explicitly in the `java` call at all; just setting LANG properly would then be enough)